# Parsing odd string with Ruby

Tags: ruby

An API responds with a string such as the following.

```
"\"APPROVED\"|\"222222\"|\"11111111\"|\"\"|\"M\"|\"\"|\"5454\"|\"MC\""
```

I was using the following code to parse

```
str = str.scan(/\w+/)
```

This worked fine, as I could str[0], str[1], etc..

Than a response such as

```
"\"DECLINED\"|\"\"|\"64243178\"|\"\"|\"\"|\"\"|\"Invalid Exp Date\"|\"\"|\"5454\"|\"MC\""
```

Trying to parse *Invalid Exp Date* ends up with simply

```
str[2] => Invalid
```

I tried the following

```
str.split("\"|")
```

But there is always a quote in the beginning

```
"Invalid Exp Date
"APPROVED
```

What is the best way to parse such a string?

Comment: It's not odd, it's just pipe-delimited values (like CSV with a `|` as a delimiter)

Comment: When you include an example in your question (which is generally helpful), it's a good idea to include your desired output, here `["APPROVED", "222222",..., "MC"]`, I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightfoward solution using [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split):

```
s = "\"APPROVED\"|\"222222\"|\"11111111\"|\"\"|\"M\"|\"\"|\"5454\"|\"MC\""

s.gsub('"','').split('|')
  #=> ["APPROVED", "222222", "11111111", "", "M", "", "5454", "MC"]
```

Comment: That's actually more of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use the [standard CSV parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) for this, for example:

```
> s = "\"APPROVED\"|\"222222\"|\"11111111\"|\"\"|\"M\"|\"\"|\"5454\"|\"MC\""
> CSV.parse(s, :col_sep => '|')
 => [["APPROVED", "222222", "11111111", "", "M", "", "5454", "MC"]]
```

CSV covers more than just Comma Separated Values, a pipe is just as good a separator as a comma.